# Edit Post PHP Script Blank Screen When Submitting Edited Post

Tags: php

I recently took on a small web development project to create an online portfolio and blog. I have been fiddling with some PHP code to edit blog posts on the site which has given me a few issues. The biggest of which is what happens when i submit the changed post to the database. When I submit the post, i get nothing but a blank screen, I am currently at a loss. If any more info is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance.

My try:

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
include('db.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{ 
    $id=$_GET['id']; 
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) 
    { 
        htmlspecialchars($title); 
        htmlspecialchars($content); 
        strip_tags($title); 
        strip_tags($content); 
        $updated= mysql_query("UPDATE blog_entry SET title=$title, content=$content WHERE post_id='$id'")or die(); 
        if($updated) 
        { 
            $msg="Successfully Updated!!"; 
            echo $msg; 
            header('Location:blog.php'); 
        } 
    } 
} //update ends here ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: paste what you have tried

Comment: <?php 
ob_start();
include('db.php');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
 htmlspecialchars($title);
 htmlspecialchars($content);
 
  strip_tags($title);
  strip_tags($content);
  
  $updated= mysql_query("UPDATE blog_entry SET 
  title=$title, content=$content WHERE post_id='$id'")or die();
  
  
  if($updated)
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  echo $msg;
  header('Location:blog.php');
  }
}
}  //update ends here
ob_end_flush();
?>

Comment: i realise this is poorly formatted, i apologise

Comment: `echo $msg; 
            header('Location:blog.php');` won't work even with `ob_start();`. You can't echo and have a header. It's one or the other.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. It's pretty clear that you didn't quote string values.

Answer (score 0):

These four lines have no effects:

```
htmlspecialchars($title); 
htmlspecialchars($content); 
strip_tags($title); 
strip_tags($content);
```

You have to assign the result to something:

```
$title   = htmlspecialchars( $title ); 
$content = htmlspecialchars( $content ); 
$title   = strip_tags( $title ); 
$content = strip_tags( $content );
```

Also note that with above code single quotes (`'`) will not be correctly escaped. Consider using:

```
$title   = mysql_real_escape_string( $title ); 
$content = mysql_real_escape_string( $content );
```

Then, you have to wrap by single quotes your field values:

```
$updated = mysql_query( "UPDATE blog_entry SET title='$title', content='$content' WHERE post_id='$id'" ) or die();
#                                                    ↑      ↑          ↑        ↑
```

And, for a better error control, add something into your `die()`:

```
$updated = mysql_query( ... ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

#### Please note:

> **mysql_** syntax was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and **it was removed** in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **[MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)** extension should be used.

(from PHP Official site)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I realise that the first four lines given did not do anything I forgot to remove them in my code. I have adjusted the code to include the changes you suggested, however now when the post is submitted, it inserts empty space into the database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know what's in the query and in the POST variables. Print it before executing it.

Comment: I printed the POST variables which are empty

Comment: So what I did was echo the contents of the title and content variables and then halted the code. The contents are empty.